# How do I customize the Window Titlebar in a Windows App SDK (WIN UI/Project Reunion) Project?

Tags: xaml, windows-community-toolkit, winui-3, windows-template-studio, windows-app-sdk

I'm trying to build an app using the new Widows App SDK. I used the Windows Community Toolkit to create the application.

After consulting the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar?view=winui-3.0), I tried this:

On the first page that my app displays, I created a Textblock:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello" x:Name="CustomTitleBar" />
```

In this page's code behind, I added the following code:

```
 private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   App.MainWindow.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;
   App.MainWindow.SetTitleBar(CustomTitleBar);
   App.MainWindow.Activate();
 }
```

On the App XAML page I followed the doumentation's directions to override these values:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowCaptionBackground">Green</SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowCaptionBackgroundDisabled">LightGreen</SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowCaptionForeground">Red</SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowCaptionForegroundDisabled">Pink</SolidColorBrush>
```

This above does make the default titlebar go away. However, I am left with just the word "Hello" with no background or buttons:

[image: Screenshot of "titlebar"]

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: How are your `Page` and `Window` defined?

Comment: The main window is defined in the App.xaml.cs file with  public static Window MainWindow { get; set; } = new Window() { Title = "AppDisplayName".GetLocalized() };

Comment: I'm using the first page that's displayed in my app. It's defined like this in the code-behind: public sealed partial class MainSelectionPage : Page. In the matching XAML, it's defined like this <Page
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainSelectionPage" ...

Comment: I put the text block on the first page that's displayed in my app. (Is that the issue?)